# How do I make an exception for a syntax error in an equation

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a simple calculator in vb.net. Users can use buttons to enter in a text box, and the equals button turns the string into an equation. It works perfectly, except for that users can just enter as much operators as they want, so they can, for example, add 7*************3. That gives a syntax error, but it shows in an external window and I want it to display "Syntax Error" in the text box, not in a different window.

```
Private Sub ButtonClickMethod(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles equalsBtn.Click 'and other buttons, but I left them out

Dim button As Button = CType(sender, Button)

If button.Name = "equalsBtn" Then
            Dim equation As String = TextBox1.Text
            Dim result = New DataTable().Compute(equation, Nothing)
            TextBox1.Text = result
        End If

'other buttons

End Sub
```

want it to display "Syntax Error" in the text box, not in a different window, like it does now.

Comment: I suppose you may need to [catch the exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-the-try-catch-block-to-catch-exceptions). (On the top row of the webpage, on the left of "Feedback", there is a language option that might be "C#" by default. Change it to "VB" to see the VB syntax.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try
    Dim result = New DataTable().Compute(equation, Nothing)
    TextBox1.Text = result
Catch ex as Exception
    'TextBox1.Text = ex.Message
    TextBox1.Text = "Syntax Error"
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean in the button used for the operators. Something like operatorInAction and set it to true when the button is clicked once. Make the button print nothing, or make it unclickable while operatorInAction is true. Set operatorInAction back to false when a number is added. You can also extend this functionality to the = button so that you won't get functions like: 2*=